# Visual studio web project debug resets chrome settings every run

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

I have problem with debugging my web application from Visual Studio 2017.

I have selected Chrome as default web browser, even checked path to chrome.exe file and seems to be OK.

The problem is, that every time, when I'm starting debugging, it opens new instance of Chrome window, which seems to be completely clean. If I set some setting (for example, deselect "auto translate websites", at next debug session it is selected again.

Another thing is, that chrome session is loading without any plugins, and if I install a plugin during one session, it's not appearing at second one.

Anyone has solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your VS2017, go to Tools, Options, Debugging, General.
Make sure that option for -Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)- is NOT checked.